# Text beside vertically aligned buttons Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, I would like to have vertical buttons with text beside them. However, when I put any text after the  tag it puts it on a new line. Any idea of how I can keep it on the same line. Thanks!

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <div class="row text-center">
      <form action="" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">            
        <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">

          <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" value="0">Option A
          </label> Some text

          <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" value="1">Option B
          </label> Some more text

          <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" value="2">None of Above
          </label> Even more text

        </div>
     </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: have you tried using **input-group** class?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I use input-groups it changes my button to a button with radio button inside and it also makes them all different widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `form-group`. that's all! and for hiding `radio` use this:

```
.form-group input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```css
.form-group input[type="radio"] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.form-group label {
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}

.form-group span {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row text-center">
  <form action="" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" value="0">Option A
            </label>
        <span>Some text</span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" value="1">Option B
            </label>
        <span>Some text</span>
      </div>
      
       <div class="form-group">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
            <input type="radio" value="2">None of above
            </label>
        <span>Some text</span>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This look great. However, it still wraps text if it is too long e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/tqdq1o46/ Any idea how to prevent this?

Comment: You set your desire `width` to prevent this https://jsfiddle.net/tqdq1o46/2/ @themush

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to make inline radio buttons, you could try something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
  <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
  <form>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3
    </label>
  </form>
</div>
```

This will display all the text and radio buttons next to each other.
The class `.radio-inline` will put the text next to the radio button.

If you want each radio button on a new line, you could just modify this code and put a `div` around each `label` and button.  Give the div a class of maybe `.col-xs-12` so that it takes 100% of the space, which would cause your new radio button to start on a new page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not the desired behavior I want. I would like vertical buttons of the same width, with no padding between then, and text to their right.

Comment: What do you mean when you say vertical buttons?

Comment: btn-group-vertical